# Module not found: Can't resolve '@fuse/core/FuseTheme' in 'C:\Projects\yarn_erp_frontend-master\yarn_erp_frontend\src\app'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fuse

[image]Please will you provide answer for my question? i am using module this:->***import FuseTheme from '@fuse/core/FuseTheme';***

Comment: I was try it instructions but not able to fix this issue:->
To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try!

Comment: you can install node modules ,we should give most preference for:-> yarn install.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

***1.***May be it's helpful for you, you can first set root directory of '@fuse/core/NavLinkAdapter' from your src file component,i was fix it by using this root directory:-***import NavLinkAdapter from '../../../../@fuse/core/NavLinkAdapter';***
so,you can resolve like that above Erro:Module not found: Can't resolve '@fuse/core/FuseTheme' in 'C:\Projects\yarn_erp_frontend-master\yarn_erp_frontend\src\app',following this way for fixing issue:->import FuseTheme from '../../../@fuse/core/FuseTheme';
***2.***You can must be check your app root directory of that **@fuse file** component from your **src** file than only,you will be fix it.
***3.*** Other wise did not fix that issue use can :-> Delete Node_modules and intall modules:->npm i or yarn.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/)) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
   This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if C:\Projects\yarn_erp_frontend-master\yarn_erp_frontend\node_modules\eslint is outside your project directory.
   For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls eslint in your project folder.
   This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed eslint.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!